# Check if store data has been changed or not

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have list of users which I recieved from server and I am showing in UI them in admin dashboard as follows.

[image]

Admin can browser through the list of users. Also, Admin can change any user's data and update that particular user in the server using the Update button. 
I am using NGXS localstorage plugin, so if admin closes the browser and open again, they will see their changes even if they havent saved it in server.

**Problem:**

I want to show indicate dirty data in the user form. **A form control is said to be dirty its data doesn't match with its counterpart recieved from server.**

**What I tried:**

When data is received from the server, make two copies in the store. Keep one copy clean, while store dirty data in other copy. Everytime, form control changes, compare the form control data in both store to detect if its dirty or not.

This solution works, but I don't feel like storing two versions of the data. Primarily, because I have many places in my website where I want to detect dirty data as exaplain. Storing a duplicate data wont work for me.

Is there an elegant way to solve this problem?

**Edit**

**What will not work:**
1. Saving dirty flag wont work. Because when user presses ctrl+z to restore input, dirty flag will not be changed to pristine.
2. Saving timestamp wont work for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a `dirty` flag in Angular. This is useful for checking if the original data placed on the form becomes dirty, which sounds like what you are trying to accomplish.

So all you really need to implement is something like this:

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >
<div *ngIf="name.dirty">Name is dirty.</div>
```

If you want to see if it is "dirty" compared to what is on the server, you'll need some async process to send your current form data up to the server to compare it to whatever is in your database has stored or vice versa.

See here for more information: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Comment: Thanks. But this is the wrong approach on so many levels. First, formControl.dirty does not become pristine even when user has has restored the input (by pressing ctrl +z or manually). But even if I can detect dirty data (by using detectUntillChanged etc.) that doesnt solve the problem since there are more than one user. And how would this solution play out when user closes the browser and reopens? Will dirty flag be helpful you think? This is not an answer at all.

Comment: NGXS does save the dirty flag on the form inputs. If you want to compare your data to what is on the server you will need to send your information to the server. Personally, I'd recommend having a `lastEdited` timestamp. That way, when you pull down the data model and then compare it to the server you can just send that timestamp to the server and do an initial conflicts check that way.

Comment: Even if you store timestamp or dirty flag, it will not work. Simply because it will still show dirty when user has restored the data. (And by dirty i meant, if the data is different from the data recieved from server.I updated in question as well.)

Comment: If you wan to be sure you are dirty after a reload, then the only other thing I can think of is to hash the original values. You can implement this by just concatenating the values in an ordered fashion and then feeding that to your hashing algorithm. That way you can just send the hash up to the server to see if when the server does the same hash generation it generates an identical hash. If it does not, it can send you the current model from which you can do your more in depth dirty check.

Comment: I want to solve the problem both before and after reload. Having a dirty or timestamp doesn't solve the problem even before reload as I have explained.  Also, I can't send it to the to server to check the dirty data. I don't have control on the server and APIs. But it's out of the scope of the problem that I described anyway.